# How do I compare UITableViewCell contents to a NSString?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsstring, ios8.1

I have a Core Data row that contains information regarding selected rows in a UITableView. The UITableViewCell value was obtained from an array of strings which is the 1st compare value; a NSString (which was stored in a Core Data row and is now displayed in a UITextField) is the 2nd compare value.

I want to compare the cell.textLabel to the textField so I can set the cell's accessory checkmark.

This is my code; the comparison is not working (I have verified the first comparison should be true):

```
        if([cell.textLabel isEqual: soServices.text])  {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            break;
        }
        else
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
```

I'm assuming my compare is incorrect, but have not found anything on SO or Google to indicate the correct way to do the compare.  So, how do I compare the cell.textLabel to a NSString?

Comment: Use the .text property of `cell.textLabel`, and then use `isEqualToString:`

Comment: @ZaneHelton please rewrite your comment as the answer... since both of you answered it (and it works) I don't know how to give both of you points.

Comment: You shouldn't use the cell, you should use the array to check the index. Use your model data not your view data.

Comment: There's no reason why `isEqual:` would not work, but `isEqualToString:` would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString: soServices.text])  {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            break;
        }
        else
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
```

Comment: do you know how to split the points?  Both of you answered it correctly... and I don't know how to split points (not sure it can even be done)

Comment: lol it can't be done. We both answered at the same time but he left a comment and I left an answer. I'll leave it up to you spokane just glad u fixed it.

Comment: if he answers u can upvote him and he'll get points but you can only accept one answer.

Comment: Thank you both... I really appreciate it... I upvoted both answers, and gave points to Chase because he had less points than Zane... thanks again.

Comment: thx spokane i upvoted him too so we split the points as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
if([cell.textLabel isEqual: soServices.text])  {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            break;
        }
        else
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
```

You're currently comparing a label to a string object, using `titleLabel`'s `text` property will let you to use the `isEqualToString:` method allowing you to successfully compare the two.